# When there is a large DOM content, empty file download happening. Are there any limitations? dom-to-image

Tags: dom-to-image

#### When there is a large DOM content, empty file download happening. Are there any limitations?

I am using Angular and high charts. I tried with DOM containing 200+ highchart images and static svg files. When tried to download the dom as JPEG, it is giving empty images as result.
Is there any limitation for this package?

[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-highcharts-e132vd)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-highcharts-e132vd

#### Expected behavior

Download the whole dom as image

#### Actual behavior

Downloading the empty Image as 0B size

#### Library version

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image/v/2.6.0

#### Browsers

- Chrome 118
- Firefox 119

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are limitations. `dom-to-image` is generating an image from a DOM node using HTML5 canvas. The problem is the `canvas` element. It has its limitations and they are explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#maximum_canvas_size) and the tests they did are these.

> https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/canvas-size#desktop

It also started to crash in my tests using your example for totalNumberOfCharts = 70; This generated a resolution of 599x26264 which is exceeding the Max Area (Total) calculated for canvas.